# Preventing single letter italics within a string

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to be able to use super/sub scripts without the main character being forced in to Mathematica's math italics mode.

The motivation being to preserve the font style settings on the string in question for things like plot legends and axis and so on.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or as an alternative to have sub and superscripts independent of a main character as you can in LaTeX with `$^{x}$` or `$^{_}$`

Note. I don't want to achieve this using LaTeX.

Comment: does `Style[Subscript[x, i], SingleLetterItalics -> False]` give what you need?

Comment: @m_goldberg agreed. Thanks!

Comment: I have done so.